# How to make the outcome of a boolean function to output a certain statement when the boolean is TRUE or FALSE in the main (c++)?

Tags: c++, function, boolean, factors

#### Problem

I am trying to write a program that can output all of a numbers prime factors. I started by making a function to check whether a factor is prime or not:

```
bool checkPrime() {
for (x = 1; x <= i; ++x) {
    if (x % i != 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

#### Main

```
int main() {

cout << "Enter any positive number: " << endl;
cin >> n;

cout << "Prime Factors of " << n << " are: " << endl;
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
        for (x = 1; x <= i; ++x) {
                cout << i << "   ";
        }
}
cout << "\n";
system("pause");
```

}

#### Question

How can I implement my "checkPrime" function to check whether or not I run:

```
cout << i << "   ";
```

Comment: A prime cannot be recognised by finding a single number which is not dividing cleanly. Double check your `checkPrime()`, it is always returning after checking `x` being 1. And it should take `i` as a parameter. And I think you mean `i%x` not `x%i`.

Answer (score 1):

I reckon the problem is to print the boolean return value of `checkPrime()` function as `true` or `false`. I'm not going in to the correctness of `checkPrime()` function in this answer. But for your purpose use something like the following.

`std::cout << std::boolalpha << checkPrime() << std::noboolalpha << std::endl;`

Refer: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha

I didn't look into you `checkPrime()` function, but ideally it should accept `n` as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `checkPrime` to accept an input.
2. Fix the the implementation. The current implementation is not correct.
3. Add a call to the function in `main` and output the number based on the return value of the function.

---

```
bool checkPrime(int i)
{
   // 1 and 2 are primes
   if ( i < 2 )
   {
      return true;
   }

   if ( i % 2 == 0 )
   {
      return false;
   }

   // Check with only odd numbers.
   // Division by even numbers is not necessary.
   // Even numbers greater than 2 are not prime numbers.
   // Also, you don't need to check for division by numbers greater than sqrt(i)

   for (x = 3; x*x <= i; x +=2 )
   {
      if ( i % x == 0)
      {
         return false;
      }
   }

   return true;
}
```

In `main`:

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
   if (n % i == 0 )
   {
      if ( checkPrime(i) )
      {
         cout << i << "   ";
      }
   }
}
```

You can combine the two `if` statements into one `if` statement.

```
for (i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
{
   if (n % i == 0 && checkPrime(i) )
   {
      cout << i << "   ";
   }
}
```

Comment: So I completely understand everything you have done here except I don't know why you are doing "x*x" in the condition of the for statement in the checkPrime() function.